# MySQL: Finding repeated names in my User table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find all users whose name appears at least twice in my User table.  'email' is a unique field, but the combination of 'firstName' and 'lastName' is not necessarily unique.

So far I have come up with the following query, which is very slow, and I am not even sure it is correct.  Please let me know a better way to rewrite this.

```
SELECT CONCAT(u2.firstName, u2.lastName) AS fullName
FROM cpnc_User u2
WHERE CONCAT(u2.firstName, u2.lastName) IN (

SELECT CONCAT(u2.firstName, u2.lastName) AS fullNm
FROM cpnc_User u1
GROUP BY fullNm
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

)
```

Also, note that the above returns the list of names that appear at least twice (I think so, anyway), but what I really want is the complete list of all user 'id' fields for these names.  So each name, since it appears at least twice, will be associated with at least two primary key 'id' fields.

Thanks for any help!
Jonah

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*
FROM cpnc_User u JOIN
(
    SELECT firstName, lastName
    FROM cpnc_User
    GROUP BY firstName, lastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) X on X.firstName = u.firstName AND x.lastName = u.lastName
ORDER BY u.firstName, u.lastName
```

There is no need to make up a concatenated field, just use the 2 fields separately

Comment: he need to do some kind of sub if he wants the distinct `id`'s for each record where the first name and last name appear in the table more than 1 time... doesnt he?

Comment: Id vote you up now that you have revised except that its pretty much the same as my query except i used an implied `JOIN` ;-)

Comment: Oooh.. good info. Was not aware of those points... Next time ill use `EXPLAIN` before opening my mouth :-) +1 to you good sir.

Comment: Thanks Richard too, I changed my accepted answer to yours for this refinement, but I upvoted pro for his help.

Comment: Also Richard, you explained how pro's version will work internally in MySQL, but how will your JOIN method be processed and why does it make it faster?

Comment: @Jonah / I did an explain for both and the plan comes up the same, except mine has the extra ORDER BY bit. I cannot find reference to where it says comma-joins are processed in strict order, but I have always thought that to be the case. I stand corrected on that point.

Comment: @Richard: Sill though, being explicit doesnt really hurt :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName
FROM cpnc_User u, (
  SELECT uc.firstName, uc.lastName 
  FROM cpnc_User uc 
  GROUP BY uc.firstName, uc.lastName 
  HAVING count(*) > 1
) u2
WHERE (
  u.firstName = u2.firstName
  AND u.lastName = u2.lastName
)
```

Comment: As Richard outlined in his comments using a JOIN is faster because of how the query is compiled. Both answers will work but his is faster.

Comment: Thanks prodigitalson, exactly what I wanted.  And thanks to everyone else too!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.id
     , CONCAT(u.firstName, ' ', u.lastName) AS fullname
FROM cpnc_User u
  JOIN 
  ( SELECT min(id) AS minid
         , firstName
         , lastName
    FROM cpnc_User 
    GROUP BY firstName, lastName
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) AS grp
  ON u.firstName = grp.firstName
    AND u.lastName = grp.lastName
  ORDER BY grp.minid
         , u.id
```

The `ORDER BY grp.minid` ensures that users with same first and last name stay grouped together in the output.

Comment: ahh, the having clause is what i forgot in mine.

Answer (score 2):

To experiment I created a simple table with two columns a user id, and a name. I inserted a bunch of records, including some duplicates. Then ran this query:

```
SELECT
count(id) AS count,
group_concat(id) as IDs
FROM
test
GROUP BY
`name`
ORDER BY
count DESC
```

It should give you results like this:

```
+-------+----------+
| count | IDs      |
+-------+----------+
|     4 | 7,15,4,1 | 
|     2 | 2,8      | 
|     2 | 6,13     | 
|     2 | 14,9     | 
|     1 | 11       | 
|     1 | 10       | 
|     1 | 3        | 
|     1 | 5        | 
|     1 | 17       | 
|     1 | 12       | 
|     1 | 16       | 
+-------+----------+
```

You'll need to filter out the later results using something else.

Comment: make that `GROUP BY lastname, firstname` and add a `HAVING COUNT(*)>1`

Answer (score 1):

OK, you are doing a concatenation, then doing a compare on this, which essentially means that the DB is going to have to do something to every single row of the database.

How about a slightly different approach, you are holding surname and first name separately. So first select all those instances where surname appears > 1 time in your database. Now this has cut your population down dramatically.

Now you can do a compare on the first name to find out where the matches are.

Comment: Indeed... You should use the syntax similar to what I or Richard aka cyberkiwi... avoid the `CONCAT` its not really necessary.