# 'Compact' SELECT results in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway to 'compact' the results of a SQL query?

The results look like:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ID | Firstname | Lastname |   Hobby   |     Job     |  Age   |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | John      | Doe      | (null)    | (null)      | 30     |
| 1  | John      | Doe      | Chess     | (null)      | (null) |
| 2  | Adam      | Jackson  | (null)    | Accountant  | (null) |
| 2  | Adam      | Jackson  | (null)    | (null)      | 55     |
| 3  | Michael   | Smith    | Knitting  | (null)      | (null) |
| 3  | Michael   | Smith    | (null)    | Banker      | (null) |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| ID | Firstname | Lastname |   Hobby   |     Job     |  Age   |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| 1  | John      | Doe      | Chess     | (null)      | 30     |
| 2  | Adam      | Jackson  | (null)    | Accountant  | 55     |
| 3  | Michael   | Smith    | Knitting  | Banker      | (null) |
+----+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

I tried using `GROUP BY` but it only accepts the first custom field from the database for each person.

I've setup a SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39563/2

The setup is a little odd but I need to keep that structure due to the database I'm working on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532186/mysql-finding-repeated-names-in-my-user-table

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `max` aggregate function an `group by` to flatten the result like this:

```
select 
  p.id as "User ID", 
  p.firstname Firstname, 
  p.lastname as Lastname,
  max(case when cf.fieldname = 'Hobby' then cfv.value end) as "Hobby",
  max(case when cf.fieldname = 'Job'   then cfv.value end) as "Job",
  max(case when cf.fieldname = 'Age'   then cfv.value end) as "Age"
from CustomFields cf 
join CustomFieldValues cfv on cfv.fieldid = cf.id
join People p on cfv.relid = p.id
where cf.fieldname in ('Hobby', 'Job', 'Age')
group by p.id, p.firstname, p.lastname 
order by p.id;
```

Also, string literals should be enclosed in single-quotes, and you can use aliases to reduce the query text and make it more readable.

[Your Fiddle, updated](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39563/20)

Comment: Good Answer. Can you please tell me how max will work in this query

Comment: @Arvaan Thr group by will for a group for every combo of id, firstname and lastname, and the max function will take the highest value for the case expressions and since one of the two possible values is null that won't be selected.

Comment: Fantastic! Is there any slight variation to only show People who have all 3 fields filled in? (i.e remove all rows with 'null' results)?

Comment: @user2562674 You can add a where clause to exclude people that are missing any values (`where cf.fieldname = 'Age' and cfv.value is not null` etc) or something similar.

Comment: WHERE will not work, you need to put it in HAVING instead: `having Hobby is not null 
   and Job is not null
   and age is not null`

Comment: @dnoeth yes, you're absolutely correct of course. I'm still half asleep and wasn't thinking clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function in your group by function for string values and the max function for numeric fields.

```
SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, 
   GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Hobby IS NOT NULL THEN Hobby END) AS Hobby,
   GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Job IS NOT NULL THEN Job END AS Job, 
   MAX(Age) AS Age 
FROM TableGROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the MAX-calculation into a Derived Table to apply aggregation before the Join. This will increase performance:

```
select p.id as "User ID", p.firstname Firstname, p.lastname as Lastname,
cf.Hobby,
cf.Job,
cf.Age
from 
 (
   select cfv.relid,
      max(case when cf.fieldname = "Hobby" then cfv.value end) as "Hobby",
      max(case when cf.fieldname = "Job" then cfv.value end) as "Job",
      max(case when cf.fieldname = "Age" then cfv.value end) as "Age"
   from CustomFields as cf inner join CustomFieldValues as cfv
     on cfv.fieldid = cf.id
   where cf.fieldname = "Hobby"
      or cf.fieldname = "Job"
      or cf.fieldname = "Age"
   group by cfv.relid
/* -- apply additional conditions here, e.g. "all three fields must be set"
   having Hobby is not null 
      and Job is not null
      and age is not null 
*/
 ) as cf
inner join People as p
   on cf.relid = p.id
order by p.id
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bc034/4)